# Unable to store data in vuex "State"

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I am unable to store the data from the API in the state, is there any issue in my code?

I am not able to `console.log(state.token)` or `state.token` from the mutations.

My Store

```js
export const AUTH_MUTATIONS = {
    SET_USER: 'SET_USER',
    SET_PAYLOAD: 'SET_PAYLOAD',
    LOGOUT: 'LOGOUT',
}
export const state = () => ({
    token: null,
    userdata: [],
    data: [],
})

export const mutations = {
    [AUTH_MUTATIONS.SET_USER] (state, { userdata }) {
        state.userdata = userdata
      },
    
    [AUTH_MUTATIONS.SET_PAYLOAD] (state, { token }) {
        state.token = token
    },
}

export const actions = {
    async login ({ commit, dispatch }, { email_id, password }) {
        const { data: {data: { user, token } } } = await this.$axios.post('http://18.xxx.246.xxx:5000/api/v1/users/login', 
            {
                email_id,
                password
            })
            // console.log(user)
            // console.log(token)
            
            commit(AUTH_MUTATIONS.SET_USER, user)
            commit(AUTH_MUTATIONS.SET_PAYLOAD, token)
            // console.log(AUTH_MUTATIONS.SET_USER, user)
    },
}

export const getters = { 
    isAuthenticated: (state) => {
      return state.token && state.token !== ''
    },
}
```

Comment: You expect an object with `token` property as a payload but a payload is token itself

Comment: how do i solve it??

Comment: The way function signature would match. Like `commit(AUTH_MUTATIONS.SET_PAYLOAD, { token })`

Comment: oh thank you it fixed the issue with token, but when i  did same with 
```commit(AUTH_MUTATIONS.SET_USER, {user})``` its saying undefined ??

Comment: when i try to check in vue dev tool i am getting this response
vueDevtools -> VuexMutations -> auth/SET_USER 

```payload:Object
user:Object
email:"test@gmail.com"
first_name:"Test"
last_name:"User"
phone_number:"9876543210"
```

Comment: Because it's really undefined this way. You called the property userdata for some reason

Comment: Thank you it solved the issue but when i try to access the state i am unable get the data

```this.$store.state.auth.user
```
console.log response
```[__ob__: Observer]
length
: 
0
__ob__
: 
Observer {value: Array(0), shallow: false, mock: false, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array
```
however i can get the token if i try to console.log it

Comment: It's unknown what's the problem, but considering that token is there and user isn't, it's probably because user/userdata was mishandled somehow

Comment: Yes clueless on how to solve this, followed same step for both token and user but only can console.log token state for some reason user is not storing in the state, but in the mutation i can see user data. is it may be because user is an array of data and token is one single data??

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem . It's unclear what's your current code and data

Answer (score 0):

In your action you need to take in `state` in the destructured parameters like this: `{ commit, dispatch, state }` then you will be able to access your `state` and log `state.token`.

If it's still `null` after that point then you should debug it to ensure that you're setting it correctly in the mutation itself.

Comment: ```{ commit, dispatch, state }``` i tried this however when i try to 
```[AUTH_MUTATIONS.SET_PAYLOAD] (state, { token }) {
        state.token = token,
        console.log(token)
    },
```
i am getting ```undefined``` log

Comment: @BeingMR.G use your Vue devtools to see what is passed to your store.

Comment: in Vue Devtools -> Vuex Mutations -> i am getting

```payload:"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzNzI3MjI4OGU4MTBkOGZjYzc4MjFlNSIsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJtb2JpbGUiOiI5ODc2NTQzMjEwIiwiaWF0IjoxNjcwNjgxMTI4LCJleHAiOjE2NzA3MjQzMjh9.MAKw5LX7Ya2so-P88vZqwNr8fp6p-CxIXRY__CSlwUM"
state:Object
auth:Object
data:Array[0]
token:undefined
userdata:undefined```

Comment: @BeingMR.G that tells you what you need to know... your `token` is `undefined`. This answer should solve your problem once you figure out why your data is `undefined`